# Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.4.1?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm import new app and `Gradle` getting error (Android Studio):

> Failed to resolve: com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.4.1

My `Gradle`: https://jsfiddle.net/kms7ne07/

How to fix it? Thanks.

p/s: This code too long to write in this. Sr about it.

Answer (score 4):

Check their Github to know how to set gradle https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Into your project build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Into your app module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I had fix it by `allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}`, btw, thank.